# Best method for creating a testable singleton in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, singleton

I have a class which follows the Singleton pattern as follows. In a Python module `automaton.py` I have:

```
class Automaton(object):
    def launch_probe(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'launched') and self.launched:
            return
        print "Launched!"
        self.launched = True

automaton = Automaton()
```

I am calling methods on the object from within from a variety of other modules. Nowhere else will I instantiate the class and I expect to be calling methods or accessing properties often so it's nice to keep access to it simple like this:

```
from automaton import automaton

automaton.launch_probe()
print 'Status:'
print automaton.launched
```

However, now I am working on better testing this code and would like to reset the singleton between unit tests in setUp().

```
import automaton

def setUp():
    automaton.automaton = automaton.Automaton()
```

However, this doesn't get the job done as other loaded modules have a reference to the original Singleton. I could switch to a pattern where I grab the singleton with `Automaton.get_instance()` or just import the module and refer to the variable inside that module, but I find that this make the main production code more verbose and harder to follow. I had considered trying to make the `automaton` variable a descriptor so it has intelligence, but discovered that descriptors only work in classes. The final approach I was considering was just trying to re-initialize the existing instance of `Automaton` by clearing it's dictionary and calling it's `__init__` method. What's the recommended approach for something like this?

Comment: There are lots of possible solutions and maybe not only one recommended approach (imho). I would add a 'private' _reset() method that ensures a clean startup (wherever needed, especially in tests). However, do you really need a class ? your singleton may just be the automaton module itself (as it is an object) and defines functions...

Comment: The benefit of using a class is that all the state is buried in a `__dict__` of it's instance so it's still easier to reset for testing than the global module space which includes other fields like `__name__` and the functions or other code that needs to stay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the many available options would be providing a method to reset the singleton to the state zero (initial state), for instance:

```
class Automaton(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()

    def reset(self):
        self.launched = False

    def launch_probe(self):
        if hasattr(self, 'launched') and self.launched:
            return
        print("Launched!")
        self.launched = True

automaton = Automaton()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import unittest

    class Test(unittest.TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            automaton.reset()

        def test1(self):
            automaton.launch_probe()
            self.assertEqual(automaton.launched, True)

        def test2(self):
            self.assertEqual(automaton.launched, False)

    unittest.main()
```